# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': not a valid selector

Tags: selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am writing automation UI tests for my web page using selenium.
I have an element on the web page which I am testing:

```
<&lt input type="checkbox" id="screening_questions[0].multiple_choice[0]-dealbreakerField" value="on" style="position: absolute; cursor: inherit; pointer-events: all; opacity: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2; left: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;>
```

Since the element has id attribute, so I tried to locate it by using its id value but it didn't work.

If I search for that element in chrome console as:

```
$('#screening_questions[0].multiple_choice[0]-dealbreakerField')
```

I get the exception: Uncaught DOMException:

```
Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': '#screening_questions[0].multiple_choice[0]-dealbreakerField' is not a valid selector.
```

I thought it will be pretty straight forward to locate it given its id value. Could you please suggest what could be wrong here?

Comment: You need to escape special characters, or use `getElementById()`.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for your reply. Which special characters are the problem here that I need to escape?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': '#screening_questions[0].multiple_choice[0]-dealbreakerField' is not a valid selector.
```

...implies that the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you have adapted is **not a valid selector**.

As per the *HTML* you have shared the desired element is a `<input>` tag with `type` attribute as **`checkbox`** and to use the `id` attribute you have to escape the `.` characters and you can use either of the following options :

- *cssSelector* :

  ```
  "input[id=\"screening_questions[0].multiple_choice[0]-dealbreakerField\"][type='checkbox']"
  ```
- *xpath* :

  ```
  "//input[@id=\"screening_questions[0].multiple_choice[0]-dealbreakerField\"][@type='checkbox']"
  ```